# Show 3d object on device live camera in Unity3d for iOS

Tags: unity, textures, ios

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to add render able Texture in Unity 3d for iOS](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/47022/how-to-add-render-able-texture-in-unity-3d-for-ios)

How render a 3d or 2d(.jpg or .png )object at device live camera in Unity3d, and this 3d object shouldn't stuck with camera. It has to show at specific point, like we can set any object in game scene at particular location.

Comment: is this the same question as http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/47022/how-to-add-render-able-texture-in-unity-3d-for-ios ? if yes, you should just edit the question, not post a new one.

Comment: Yes, This is same question. I want to get response ASAP :).

Comment: Reposting your question isn't the proper way to go.